# leetcode subset javascript code returns empty array

Tags: javascript, algorithm

i am new to algorithms and have a silly question about a leetcode problem. The problem is asking for all subsets for a given array which only contains distinct integers.

In my code, the console.log of the list array gives me what I want, which is a group of subsets of the input. But it does not pass down to result. The result returns something like this:
[ [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [] ]

Below is my code:

```html
 const subsets = (nums) => {
    let result = []; 
    let list = [];
    
    const helper = (result, list, nums, position) => {
        for (let i = position; i < nums.length; i++) {
            list.push(nums[i]);
            helper(result, list, nums, i + 1);
            list.pop();
        }
        console.log(list) // this is what I want. but it does not pass down to result!!! 
        result.push(list);
    }

    helper(result, list, nums, 0)
    return result;
}
```

Any thoughts would be awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you push the same array reference to the result set. As result, you see the array of the last loop for all arrays.

For getting all single arrays, you need to get a copy with [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) for pushing.

```
result.push(list.slice());
```

This creates a new array with all values.

```js
const subsets = (nums) => {
    let result = []; 
    let list = [];
    
    const helper = (result, list, nums, position) => {
        for (let i = position; i < nums.length; i++) {
            list.push(nums[i]);
            helper(result, list, nums, i + 1);
            list.pop();
        }
        result.push(list.slice());
    }

    helper(result, list, nums, 0);
    return result;
}

console.log(subsets([1, 2, 3]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!